# Conditional variabel name with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm building an app that will have the sourcecode available to everyone. Depending on what the end system will use (there will be a possibility to run it with `electron` and under C# `WebBrowserControl`) different global variable names need to apply.

For example.

```
<--! This should not be applied to the end product if I don't specify that -->
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const currentWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
</script>
<!-- This is the end of the conditional statement -->
```

And I also want to change name on the variable `currentWindow` to `window` in the whole app.

Can I do this in some way with a webpack plugin/loader or whatever?

I used a similair plugin to `grunt` a while back were I had these conditional statements in the code depending on that command I ran with `grunt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Webpack plugin named `DefinePlugin` that may do what you need: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    ...

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            HOST: 'electron' // or 'WebBrowserControl', etc.
        })
    ]

}
```

You can then access `HOST` as a global variable from your application code:

```
if (HOST === 'electron') {
    const electron = require('electron');
    const currentWindow = electron.remote.getCurrentWindow();
} else if (HOST === 'WebBrowserControl') {
    // etc...
}
```

Depending on how you kick off your Webpack build, you should be able to swap out the value of `HOST` in `webpack.config.js` based on the type of build you're doing.